# Firefox displays horizontal lines down the screen

Tags: firefox, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, visual-artifacts

I installed a Quadro NVS 285 graphics card recently, and ever since then Firefox will randomly display horizontal lines down the screen.

I reinstalled Firefox, and it did not fix the problem. This only happens in Firefox.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image]

NVIDIA driver version: 307.45
Firefox version: 26

Comment: Disable hardware acceleration (go to Options, and it's right there in the General tab) - if that makes it go away, it's your video card or driver.  If that doesn't resolve, see if it happens in Firefox Safe mode (should be another icon in the start menu).  If *that* resolves it, you have an add-on doing something weird.

Comment: Alright, I disabled hardware acceleration. I'll wait and see what happens. Thanks the suggestion!

Comment: The problem persists with hardware acceleration disabled. I am now running Firefox in safe-mode.

Comment: The issue appears to be caused by an addon. Thanks for the help. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it as the solution! :)

Comment: @Ripster I'm seeing the same/similar problem (only on a specific site, but not any other OS/browser combo that FF on Ubuntu). Where plugin was causing the problem for you?

Comment: It was a password manager plugin. I unfortunately do not remember the name.